# Need help to identify a three lead passive component

Tags: identification, components

Here's a picture of a damaged component salvaged from an old spectrum analyzer. The number on the component reads 226K & 253, which I presumed it as dual tantalum capacitors ( with three leads) of values 226nF and 25nF. Any advice or alternative replacement component values may please be suggested.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a dual cap. It is a 3 pin tantalum with two ground wires to reduce ESR/impedance and to avoid mounting it with wrong orientation. It has a rating of 22 uF and 25V and the K is a tolerance marking. Alternatives include 2 pin tantalum and ceramic caps as long as above ratings are known, but without schematics it is hard to know how important cap it is.

Comment: Please give diagram to show how to connect a two pin tantalum capacitor with a ceramic capacitor to form an equivalent three pin component. Thanks.